# Como fazer um login Spring Security, JSF 2.2 e ManagedBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Olá.
Preciso de uma ajuda. 
Estou configurando o Spring Security em um Projeto JSF 2.2. Utilizando Annotation.
Já consegui configurar os filtros.
Mas não entendo como configurar o ManagedBean do login para buscar no banco de dados e fazer o login no JSF.
Abaixo está minha classe de configuração do Spring Security

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("zezinho").password("123456").roles(Constantes.PERMISSAO_USER);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(Constantes.RESOURCES).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(Constantes.PUBLIC + Constantes.URL_ALL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(Constantes.PRIVATE).hasRole(Constantes.PERMISSAO_USER).anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(Constantes.PAGE_PUBLIC_URL_LOGIN)
            .successForwardUrl(Constantes.PAGE_PRIVATE_URL_PRINCIPAL)
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
```

//        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");;
    }

}

Importante Lembrar Que utilizo o Hibernate e uma Tabela Usuário.
Sendo assim.
Quero fazer a consulta do usuário no ManagedBean. e depois iniciar a sessão caso exista. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que implementar essa solução há um tempo, me baseei nesse link: http://www.programming-free.com/2016/01/spring-security-spring-data-jpa.html

Você precisa configurar o AuthenticationManagerBuilder, ex:

```
@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                // configura um encoder para a senha armazenada no banco
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

E um @Service que implemente `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UsuarioEntity user = userRepository.findByNomeUsuario(username);
    //...
    }
}
```

Abcs!

Comment: Muito Obrigado Amigo! Me Ajudou Muito!

Comment: Abraços! Tenha uma ótima semana :)